How to prompt user to turn on Bluetooth and location services in react-native?
I have a react-native app which needs Location and Bluetooth enabled. For this purpose I want to prompt the user to turn them and prompt again if they aren't turned on or turned off again.
I tried using this code:
async  getPermissions(){
        try{
            const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
                PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                {
                    title:'Locations Permission',
                    message:'Stripe needs access to your location',
                    buttonPositive:'Accept'
                }
            );
            if(granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED){
                console.log('You can use Location')
            }
            else{
                console.error('Permission not given')
            }
        }
        catch{}
    }

But it goes to the if condition. I think this code only checks if the permissions are enabled and not if the actual services are enabled or not.

Once the user have forbid to give permission then ask permission popup will not be shown again you have add in your else condition in alert that your app needs location access and add button in it to redirect user app settings from there user will give permission.
